# How to evaluate time series forecasting models developed by prophet

Tags: r, facebook, time-series

Facebook has released Prophet for forecasting time series. While the get [started page](https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#r-api) does outline how to make forecasts using predict() function but it does not say anything about methods to evaluate time-series forecasts made by prophet, say, for example examination of residuals or auto-correlation of residuals etc..
For example, the following few lines will make forecasts:

```
library(prophet)    
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- read.csv('example_wp_peyton_manning.csv') %>%  mutate(y = log(y))
df$ds <-ymd(df$ds)       # ds is now a Date type
model <- prophet(df)     # Create forecasting model
# Make data-frame with future dates for forecasting.
future <- make_future_dataframe(model, periods = 365)
# Make forecasts of these future periods
forecast <- predict(model, future)
# Calculate residuals for common dates
df1<-inner_join(forecast,df, by="ds")  
df1$residuals<-df1$y - df1$yhat
# And calculate ACF
acf(df1$residuals,lag.max = 10)
```

If I calculate 'acf' this way, the result is quite discouraging. Am I correct?

Comment: Additionally to that, since Prophet fits a regression model instead of a traditional time-series model, how does one get the R squared and Durbin-Watson autocorrelation measure of a Prophet model?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own evaluate function based on mean squared errors in order to find model error percentage. **predict(model, future)** method gives you predictions for both your existing data and 365 future data points (you don't have in your dataset).You have real data and their predictions. Let's assume that you have 1000 records and their predictions, you can find error percentage by using last 20 records or 100 records of your data and their predictions. As an example you can take a look at my own function written in python :

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

def get_error_percentage(real_stock_price, predicted_stock_price):
    print("get_error_percentage() method was called.")
    rmse = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(real_stock_price, 
    predicted_stock_price))
    # 800: avg of real_stock_price (test set)
    error_percentage = rmse / np.average(real_stock_price)
    return error_percentage
```

real_stock_price is last 20 records or 100 records of your data and predicted_stock_price is real_stock_price's predictions.
You can write your own evaluate function in R

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I was more interested in finding out auto-correlation of residuals. It is true that a function can be written to perform all these but I was wondering if some inbuilt function or a function from another package is available.

Comment: Alright, maybe you should try to create a r time series object  based on your residuals and call r acf function. In r acf documentation below, you can find required parameters and their descriptions in order to call acf function.                     https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/acf.html